# Comments on my approach to Group Theory notes?

Tags: undergraduate-education, abstract-algebra

I am working on some introductory notes for group theory. Comments on my initial approach here and any errors so far would be appreciated.

I begin with the group axioms:

1. $\forall a,b\in G:[ a+b\in G]$
2. $\forall a,b,c\in G:[ (a+b)+c=a+(b+c)]$
3. $0\in G$
4. $\forall a\in G: [a+0=a \land 0+a=a]$
5. $\forall a\in G: \exists b\in G: [a+b=0 \land b+a=0]$

Then I prove:

6. $\forall a,b \in G:[a+b=a \implies b=0]$ (All right identities are equal to $0$)
7. $\forall a,b \in G:[a+b=b \implies a=0]$ (All left identities are equal to $0$)
8. $\forall a,b,c\in G:[a+b=c+b \implies a=c]$ (+ is right-cancelable)
9. $\forall a,b,c\in G:[a+b=a+c \implies b=c]$ (+ is left-cancelable)
10. $\forall a,b,c\in G:[a+b=0 \land a+c=0 \implies b=c]$ (right inverses wrt $0$ are unique)
11. $\forall a,b,c\in G:[a+b=0 \land c+b=0 \implies a=c]$ (left inverses wrt $0$ are unique)

12.$\exists !inv: \forall a\in G: [inv(a)\in G\land a+inv(a)=0 \land inv(a)+a=0]$ (unique inverse operator exists)

Comment: Motivation is very important.  I would suggest including a lot of it.  Also, group operations are traditionally written multiplicatively rather than additively if they are not assumed abelian.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce I will probably be using these proofs in ring theory as well, so the use the symbols + and 0 makes sense here.

Comment: I'd second @MichaelJoyce's implied recommendations to give examples and motivation, as well as making clear that non-abelian groups can be considered, and there the operation is written multiplicatively. Although succinctness has a terrific appeal as a summary _after_ the fact, I think people _learning_ things benefit from a more discursive introduction to new things, with examples. Without examples, how do we know what phenomena we're trying to "fit"? Terse summary of axioms _afterward_.

Comment: @paulgarrett  I haven't given much thought to motivation. But there are plenty of motivating articles available online. Now, I just want to make sure I have the basic theory right.

Comment: Start with three representations of the cyclic group of order three (but don't tell them that): 1) $e^{2 \pi i}, e^{2 \pi i/3}$, and $e^{4 \pi i /3}$ under multiplication, 2) the permutation function $(123)$ under function composition, and 3) any matrix representation. Let them discuss "this is the same object represented three different ways"  vs. "these are three different objects" some will struggle with the abstraction, but let their classmates convince them. Provide examples of more groups. Then give the axioms and have them prove 6-12, giving examples from the three representations.

Comment: @DanChristensen It is worth mentioning the context you are teaching this in.  I assume (from looking at your user profile a bit) that you do not have a class of students, but rather these examples would exist to showcase your computer symbolic logic system?  In that case everything seems fine except for (as noted above) mathematicians almost never write $+$ for a noncommutative operation.  Your axiom 1 is also usually not needed:  either the operation is defined as a function $G \times G \to G$, in which case this is automatic, or the axioms are formulated in FOL.

Comment: I also somewhat question making basic group theory a showcase of your system if you are not very well versed in the subject.  If you want to learn it, probably best to learn it thoroughly first.

Comment: Are these notes for *teaching* group theory?  Or notes for *self-study*?  Who is the audience?  Will they be distributed or just used for planning?

Comment: @StevenGubkin  I have come around to changing the symbols since I will need to demonstrate numerical results (orders of groups, etc.). I might get into trouble with multiplication, but oh well. My axiom (1) is how I formally define a function. It works really quite well as a statement in my version of FOL. I think I am well enough versed in the rudiments of graph theory to make some useful notes for undergrads making the transition to a proof-based curriculum by means of abstract algebra. I am in the process of writing (and re-writing) a suite of formal proofs of manageable size and complexity

Comment: I have voted to close because this appears to be a question about mathematics, rather than the teaching of mathematics.

Comment: Thats funny! At MSE, they thought it would be better suited here. Close it if you like. I think I have the answer to my question in these comments anyway. I will post a link here to the end result if I am happy with it. Instructors can pass it on students if they like it.Thanks all.

Comment: Here is the formal proof for Part 1: http://www.dcproof.com/GroupTheory1.htm  More to come.

Comment: @DanChristensen I think the problem is that you haven't made it clear what you are asking. The question seems to be 'is this a good way to present this material', which belongs here rather than Math.SE. But your comments give the impression you are closer to asking 'is this maths correct', which doesn't belong here.

Comment: Yes, seconding @JessicaB's comment: the title does give the impression that the question is about presentation (to students?), while it's really about machine-proof set-up. Very different audiences for such writing, and very different questions.

Comment: @mweiss I hope these notes, in their ultimate form (not what you see here), will be  useful as a resource for instructors or as a supplement to texts and lectures for undergrads. I think it is important for students to at least know what a formal proof looks like, and to understand the underlying principles.

Comment: Here is Part 2: http://www.dcproof.com/GroupTheory2a.htm http://www.dcproof.com/GroupTheory2b.htm

Answer (score 4):

My comment is: what are you aiming to achieve with these notes? My instinctive reaction is that you are doing too much and not getting the student to do enough. Writing out a full exposition is fine if the notes are for reference or you only care about memorisation, but won't help that much if the aim is to learn to do mathematics.

Comment: These notes are meant as a resource for instructors and a supplement to textbooks and lectures on group theory and the general methods of rigorous mathematical proof for undergrads. Students should know what a truly formal proof looks like.